# HP Universal Configuration Management Database UCMDB Starting Point

Tags: version-control, tfs, information-retrieval, hp-quality-center, cmdb

I'm working with a contractor installed UCMDB instance that was put in before I started.  What are some good starting points that I should read to get up to speed so that I can ask good questions of the implementing consultants?

We have a limited budget, so I want to be as knowledgable as possible when I talk to them to make sure that I am maximizing the time spent.

It looks like all of the models that are 'mapped' (if that is the correct term) are pointing to CIs that are all infrastructure and installed file based.  I would like to tap into our TFS and HP Quality Center installations to put additional CIs in the database, but am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what version of uCMDB are you running? Standalone or integrated into BSM (RTSM)? First of all you need to determine your support status with HP SSO. You or the company you work for should have an SAID which allows you to log support cases, browse support forums and the like. Further, dig into the uCMDB install and locate all PDFs which came with the product. For release 9 this would be at \[server][drive]\hp\UCMDB\deploy\ucmdb-docs\docs\eng\pdfs. There are a quite a few places to check out for more information on uCMDB and DDM, go check out http://leveragediscovery.com (Resources section) for some good links.
Regarding your stated desire to integrate with TFS and QC I could recommend you join the weekly DDM practitioner's forum (moderated by Jody Roberts @ HP R&D). There's bound to be someone at the table who has some experience with that type of integration.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've joined the practitioner's forum, but have not yet made it to a meeting.  It is at an unfortunate time for my commute...

We are currently using version 9.03 of the CMDB and DDM.  We can log support cases, and currently have one in about some files not being discovered.